# Check if record has ascii char

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can you check a single record if it consists of ascii characters?
e.g.:

I have companies database and I want to reject all that have special chars from different alphabets in name. How to identify them?

- `CatCompany` - Ascii chars only
- `CzęściCompany` - ascii and non ascii chars
- `żąć` - non ascii only

Comment: It's not clear to me what are you really want to do, do you want to prevent inserting some characters to table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it was not an answer but [a link to another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138350/how-to-check-for-non-ascii-characters) it solved my problem.
Simple e.g. how I wanted use it on Northwind database:

```
SELECT CompanyName      
FROM Customers      
WHERE CompanyName not LIKE '%[' + CHAR(127)+ '-' +CHAR(255)+']%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
```

Results of this query are all companies that have only ascii characters in their names.